# C++ Matrix horizontal concat

Tags: c++, matrix

I have 2 matrix, for example:

```
     a1 a2 a3 a4        a5 a6 a7 a8
M1 = b1 b2 b3 b4   M2 = b5 b6 b7 b8
     c1 c2 c3 c4        c5 c6 c7 c8
```

what i want is get a matrix concat like this:

```
     a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8
Mr = b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
     c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
```

fast as possible cause my program is all based on this concat at speed of 50MHz.(Sound acquisition)
It's actually neded for read a single line fast(each line is a microphone flow).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: give it a shot and if you have a specific question, post your code and the specific question.  stack overflow isn't here to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save your matrix as a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, where the inner vector is one of your rows, you can use `std::insert` to perform a concatenation of the rows of your matrices.

```
 vector1.insert( vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end() );
```

You might also find a library such as [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) useful. I has a function `join_rows( A, B )`, which is doing, what you ask for. With some chance this will have a better performance, than what you can program yourself.